# Why i'm getting 500 server error php?

Tags: php, html, redirect

Actually, when user enter his email and password an hit enter enter..it shows server error!

error 500

But when i refresh page it works fine...

why i'm getting server error at first attempt of login..

here is my code:

login.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);


            $stmt = $user_login->runQuery("SELECT * FROM jusers WHERE jemail=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {   

                    if($userRow['jpass']==md5($upass))
                    {    

                     $_SESSION['user']= array(
                        'juid' =>$userRow['juid'],
                        'username'=>$userRow['jemail'],
                        'password'=>$userRow['jpass'],
                        'role'=>$userRow['role']
                     );

                     $role= $_SESSION['user']['role'];

                      switch ($role) {

                        case 'admin':

                            header("Location : super_admin.php");
                            break;

                        case 'user' :

                             header("Location : admin_user.php");
                             break;
                      }


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $errMSG =" <div class='alertmsg alert'>
                                    <a class='clostalert'>close</a>
                                    <strong>Warning!</strong> Wrong password </div> ";              
                    }

            }
            else
            {

                $errMSG = " <div class='errormsg alert'>
                            <a class='clostalert'>close</a>
                            <strong>Error!</strong> Wrong credentials!</div> ";            
            }
```

And my admin_user.php after user logins correctly

```
    <?php

 session_start();
 require_once 'class.user.php';
 $admin_user = new USER();

 if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){

   header('location:login.php');

}

if($_SESSION['user']['role']=='admin'){

 header('location:super_admin.php');

}


 if(!$admin_user->is_logged_in())
{
    $admin_user->redirect('login.php');
}

 $sid = $_SESSION['user']['juid'];

   $stmt = $admin_user->runQuery('select jname from jusers where juid = :sid');
   $stmt->bindParam(':sid', $sid);
   $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

     extract($row);

     }

?>
```

What wrong in this...

Any advice will be greatly thankfull...

Comment: Check your error logs, or enable error reporting to find out what the error message is.

Comment: Always append exit(); right after header redirections so no other codes are  executed after redirection call.

Comment: Response header name 'Location ' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: http://localhost/justshow.in/login.php   ......Error log display this message

Answer (score 1):

So not add space `' '` in location. change your switch case as below:

```
switch ($role) {

                        case 'admin':

                            header("Location:super_admin.php");
                            break;

                        case 'user' :

                             header("Location:admin_user.php");
                             break;
                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) without the space before the `:`

`header("Location: super_admin.php");` or `header("Location: admin_user.php");`